# Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly with Targetframework .NET 4.5.2 causes NullReference Exception on CrmServiceClient.Execute

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, .net-4.5, tls1.2, dynamics-365

We are connecting to Dynamics 365 CRM with the following code in a plain console app targeting .NET 4.5.2.

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest req2 = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest();
        req2.EntityFilters = Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.EntityFilters.Entity;

        CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(
            "svccrm@contoso.com",
            CrmServiceClient.MakeSecureString("secret"),
            "EMEA", "contoso",
            useUniqueInstance: true,
            useSsl: true, isOffice365: true);

        try
        {
            //error with target framework 4.5.2
            var resp2 = conn.Execute(req2) as RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse;
        }
        catch
        {
            string lastError = conn.LastCrmError;
        }
    }
```

The following nuget packages are in the packages.config

```
<package id="Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies" version="9.0.2.5" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.CrmSdk.Deployment" version="9.0.2.4" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.CrmSdk.Workflow" version="9.0.2.4" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly" version="9.0.2.7" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.22.302111727" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
```

When I run this code I get a NullReferenceException at
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient.Execute(OrganizationRequest request) with a LastCrmError of

> Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM************ Exception - RetrieveAllEntities : Execute (RetrieveAllEntities) request to CRM from IOrganizationService |=> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

As soon as I change the target Framework to 4.6.2 it works just fine. The thing is that we host this code inside an SQL Server Integration Services package and for some reason, on Windows 2016, SSIS always falls back to the 4.5.2 framework.

We are investigating this as well but for now the question remains, if the Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly package is supposed to work with 4.5.2 (the nuget readme says yes) or if this is a bug in the SDK.

The latest .NET 4.7.X frameworks have been installed on the 2016 server and my win 10 dev machine while both face the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 9, [Dynamics 365 is enforcing TLS 1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4051700) and because .NET 4.5 uses TLS 1.1 as default you're getting this error.
 In the previous article you'll find that the solution for client applications is the one you've already tried:

> Recompile your client applications using .NET framework **4.6.2** or higher.

There're some articles on how to enforce TLS 1.2 from a SSIS package ([here](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000926174-How-to-enable-TLS-1-2-for-SSIS-2012-packages) and [here](https://visakhm.blogspot.com/2018/08/ssis-tips-enforcing-tls-12-for-ssis.html)), but unfortunately I haven't tried them. If these don't help, you can workaround the error by updating the `SchUseStrongCrypto` registry setting to DWORD:00000001 as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4040243/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-for-configuration-manager) (Enable TLS 1.2 for dependent components/Update .NET Framework section).

Comment: Oh my, that sounds like the issue. Will try that ASAP on my end.

Comment: I can confirm that this works when setting the reg key as described here: https://johnlouros.com/blog/enabling-strong-cryptography-for-all-dot-net-applications

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the above code successfully using 4.5.2.

Check your app.config. Add the below tag and try.

`<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>`

Thanks

Comment: Already had that in the app.config but no luck. Did you get a response from Dynamics 365? What Windows version are you running on?

Comment: Version 1710 (9.1.0.1118)

Comment: Also please check your connection object (conn) is null or not?